# Action is not redirecting to another Action in play-framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

```
class InstitutionController extends Controller {
    def updateInstitution = Action { implicit request =>
        {
          request.body.asJson.get.validate[GallreyJsonValidationForUpdate].fold(
            valid = {
              updateInstitution =>
                {
                        Redirect(routes.GalleryController.updateGallreyObject()).flashing("uuid"-    >updateInstitution.uuid,"institutionName"->updateInstitution.institutionName,"details"->updateInstitution.details)
                }
            },
            invalid = {
              errors =>
                {
                  val json=commonUtils.getResponse(Http.Status.BAD_REQUEST, ServerResponseMessages.VALIDATION_FAILED,JsError.toJson(errors))
                  log.error("sending error in json{}", json)
                  BadRequest(json)
                }
            })
        }
      }
```

this is the Action i am redirecting to

```
class GalleryController extends Controller {
def updateGallreyObject = Action { implicit request =>
  {
       val uuid=request.flash.get("uuid")
       val institutionName=request.flash.get("institutionName")
       val details=request.flash.get("details")
       Ok("some details")
 }}
}
```

here is the curl file i am using

```
contentType="Content-type: application/json";

data='{  "uuid" : "123" , "institutionName" : "abc" , "details" : "some details" 

 }';
echo "    "
echo "------------------   Sending Data   ------------------"
echo "    "
echo "Content-Type : " $contentType
echo "Data : " $data


echo "    "
echo "------------------     Response     ------------------" 
echo "    "
echo "    "


curl --include --request POST --header "Content-type: application/json"  --data "$data" http://localhost:9000/institution/update
```

the response i am getting is

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Location: /gallery/update
Set-Cookie: PLAY_FLASH=uuid=123 &institutionName=abc&details=some+details; Path=/; HTTPOnly
Date: Sat, 04 Mar 2017 14:40:29 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

here is the route

```
POST   /institution/update                                  controllers.InstitutionController.updateInstitution
```

why its not redirecting to  `updateGallreyObject` Action ? what i am doing wrong please help ,i want it to redirect to `updateGallreyObject` Action with the data please help, I am expecting this response "some details"

Update i already have this route

```
POST   /gallery/update                                  controllers.GalleryController.updateGallreyObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need a mapping for your `updateGallreyObject` in routes.

```
GET /galery                    controllers.GalleryController.updateGallreyObject
```

P.S. Reformat your code before posting it here. You'd probably want to use external formatter such as Scalariform or Scalafmt.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `match` but `fold`, just like in the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Putting-it-all-together

```
request.body.asJson.get.validate[GallreyJsonValidationForUpdate] match {
  case s: JsSuccess[GallreyJsonValidationForUpdate] => {
    val updateInstitution: GallreyJsonValidationForUpdate = s.get

    Redirect(routes.GalleryController.updateGallreyObject()).flashing("uuid"-    >updateInstitution.uuid,"institutionName"->updateInstitution.institutionName,"details"->updateInstitution.details)
  }
  case e: JsError => {
    val json=commonUtils.getResponse(Http.Status.BAD_REQUEST, ServerResponseMessages.VALIDATION_FAILED,JsError.toJson(errors))
    log.error("sending error in json{}", json)
    BadRequest(json)
  }
}
```